# Custom Calculator Wordpress without plugin Script

Tags: php, html, wordpress, calculator

Hello I wrote with some guides a calculator with 3 input fields for calculating the heart rate for cardio sessions but I seem to have problems implementing them into my wordpress

While trying it out in a tryouteditor in web it is working (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_div_default_css)

In wordpress it only shows me the code (yes i made input in HTML)
I do not have a server, so I access wordpress only with browser and have no use of plugins

Please help me
Here´s the code:

```
    <html>
    <script>
    function calc(form) {

    var D = "0";
    var E = "0";
    var A = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var B = document.getElementById("op").value;
    var C = document.getElementById("num2").value;

    if (C === "GI")
    {
    D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('5'))/parseInt('10')
    E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('6'))/parseInt('10'); 
    }
    else if(C === "A1")
    {
    D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('6'))/parseInt('10');
    E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('7'))/parseInt('10');
    }
    else if(C === "A2")
    {
    D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('7'))/parseInt('10');
    E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('8'))/parseInt('10');
    }
    else if (C === "A3")
    {
    D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('8'))/parseInt('10');
    E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('9'))/parseInt('10');
    }
    else if (C === "A4")
    {
    D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('9'))/parseInt('10');
    E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('10'))/parseInt('10');
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = D;
    document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = E;
    return false;
    }
    </script>
    <body>
    Heart Rate when waking up
    <input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" />
    <br>
    Age
    <input type="text" id="op" name="op" />
    <br>
    Intensity GI - A4
    <input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" />
    <br />
    <input type="button" value="Solve" onClick="calc(this)">

    <p id="result" name="r1">
    <p id="result2" name="r2">
    <br />
    </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Please specifiy your problems so that we al know what's wrong. Thank you!

Comment: In wordpress it only shows me the code and not that what the code should do

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to create a new page template. Create a page template like `calculator-template.php`

And then inside the file write like this way:

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Heart Calculator
*/ get_header();
?>
<script>
//your js codes
</script>
<!-- Write your html codes. Do not include body tag -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Now you should go to Wordpress Dashboard>Add New Page>Select the `Heart Calculator` page template from the right widget. And publish it!

For using **wordpress.com**

Directly copy and paste the code in the page editor of wordpress. Make sure you select the **text mode**

```
<script>
function calc(form) {
var D = "0";
var E = "0";
var A = document.getElementById("num1").value;
var B = document.getElementById("op").value;
var C = document.getElementById("num2").value;
if (C === "GI")
{
D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('5'))/parseInt('10')
E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('6'))/parseInt('10'); 
}
else if(C === "A1")
{
D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('6'))/parseInt('10');
E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('7'))/parseInt('10');
}
else if(C === "A2")
{
D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('7'))/parseInt('10');
E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('8'))/parseInt('10');
}
else if (C === "A3")
{
D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('8'))/parseInt('10');
E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('9'))/parseInt('10');
}
else if (C === "A4")
{
D = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('9'))/parseInt('10');
E = parseInt(A)+((parseInt('220')-parseInt(B)-parseInt(A))*parseInt('10'))/parseInt('10');
}
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = D;
document.getElementById("result2").innerHTML = E;
return false;
}
</script>

Heart Rate when waking up
<input type="text" id="num1" name="num1" />
<br>
Age
<input type="text" id="op" name="op" />
<br>
Intensity GI - A4
<input type="text" id="num2" name="num2" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Solve" onClick="calc(this)">

<p id="result" name="r1">
<p id="result2" name="r2">
<br />
</p>
```

I have just tested it and it worked!
You are good to go now!

Comment: How to I create a new page template? I found this guide 
http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/
but connecting with WINSCP to my site I only find the root directory and no wp-content:(
And where do I add the body tags ? Sry i do not normally write codes

Comment: Ok. Install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/add-custom-page-template/ . First follow what I said, then install the plugin. Upload the template file using the plugin. Then you are good to go!

Comment: Like I said i use wordpress in browser not installed, so therefore I cannnot install plugins (like in my title no plugin)
"If you are using WordPress.com, then you cannot install plugins."

Comment: Can you send me a screenshot of WinSCP after logging in?

Comment: Thanks for your help, but still when I add this code in my public page there is only the formula. the only differences in the code is no HTML-tag and no body-tag
I typed the code in the html-mode

Comment: Do you see JS printed?

Comment: It only shows the code after the script part. 
http://imgur.com/a/XU5Tm = this is in editor ..... 
http://imgur.com/a/mIk3g = this is the result